# Generate crypto Random Integer beetwen min, max values

Tags: random, go

I trying to generate a random number beetwen a min value and a max value,
but seems I'm lost with this, what is wrong?

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
)

func genRandNum(min, max int8) int {
    var num int8
    binary.Read(rand.Reader, binary.LittleEndian, &num)
    return int(num*(max-min)+min)
}

func main() {
    // trying to get a random number beetwen -10 and 10
    fmt.Println(genRandNum(-10,10))
}
```

Comment: Even if you got your approach to work, it would in most cases make lower values slightly more frequent. The rand.Int function used by jmaloney is the correct way to go; it is what it was made for. Look at [the source](http://golang.org/src/pkg/crypto/rand/util.go?s=3072:3134#L96) to see how they solve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println(genRandNum(-10, 10))
}

func genRandNum(min, max int64) int64 {
    // calculate the max we will be using
    bg := big.NewInt(max - min)

    // get big.Int between 0 and bg
    // in this case 0 to 20
    n, err := rand.Int(rand.Reader, bg)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // add n to min to support the passed in range
    return n.Int64() + min
}
```

Go [play](http://play.golang.org/p/jQCzTBGn0M)

Comment: @Jzala I added some comments to the code. Does that clear it up for you?

Comment: I think there is an error here.  `rand.Int(rand.Reader, bg)` will produce numbers between 0 and bg-1 so `getRandNum` will never return 10. You can fix it with  `bg := big.NewInt(max - min + 1)`

Comment: @siritinga, you're right but only if you want include the upper extreme.